# Unintended line across X axis of density plot (r)

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I am trying to identify why I have a purple line appearing along the x axis that is the same color as "Prypchan, Lida" from my legend. I took a look at the data and do not see any issues there.

```
ggplot(LosDoc_Ex, aes(x = LOS)) +
  geom_density(aes(colour = AttMD)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  xlab("Length of Stay") +
  ylab("Distribution") +
  labs(title = "LOS Analysis * ",
       caption = "*exluding Residential and WSH",
       color = "Attending MD: ")
```

[image: LOS Analysis by Doc]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! As it stands, this question is off topic since it is asking for debugging help without a reproducible example. Please put together a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question to include it. Some R specific tips for that are here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 6):

Usually I'd wait for a reproducible example, but in this case, I'd say the underlying explanation is really quite straightforward:

`geom_density()` creates a **polygon**, not a **line**.

Using a sample dataset from ggplot2's own package, we can observe the same straight line below the density plots, covering the x-axis & y-axis. The colour of the line simply depends on which plot is on top of the rest:

```
p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, colour = cut)) +
  geom_density()
```

[image: plot]

**Workaround 1**: You can manually calculate the density values yourself for each colour group in a new data frame, & plot the results using `geom_line()` instead of `geom_density()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
diamonds2 <- diamonds %>%
  nest(-cut) %>%
  mutate(density = map(data, ~density(.x$carat))) %>%
  mutate(density.x = map(density, ~.x[["x"]]),
         density.y = map(density, ~.x[["y"]])) %>%
  select(cut, density.x, density.y) %>%
  unnest()

ggplot(diamonds2, aes(x = density.x, y = density.y, colour = cut)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image: plot with new data frame]

**Workaround 2**: Or you can take the data generated by the original plot, & plot *that* using `geom_line()`. The colours would need to be remapped to the legend values though:

```
lp <- layer_data(p)
if(is.factor(diamonds$cut)) {
  col.lev = levels(diamonds$cut) 
} else {
  col.lev = sort(unique(diamonds$cut))
}
lp$cut <- factor(lp$group, labels = col.lev)

ggplot(lp, aes(x = x, y = ymax, colour = cut)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image: plot with data frame from original plot]

Comment: Thank you very much. This is my first stack post and will provide a reproducible example in the future. Your workarounds worked great!

Comment: Another workaround is `geom_density_line()` from the ggridges package. I wrote it because I was tired of needing workarounds for this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53773892/4975218

Comment: Or simply use `geom_line()` with `stat = "density"` if you don't want the filled area.

Answer (score 5):

There are two simple workarounds. First, if you only want lines and no filled areas, you can simply use `geom_line()` with the density stat:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = stat(density), colour = cut)) +
  geom_line(stat = "density")
```

[image]

Note that for this to work, we need to set the `y` aesthetic to `stat(density)`.

Second, if you want the area under the lines to be filled, you can use `geom_density_line()` from the ggridges package. It works exactly like `geom_density()` but draws a line (with filled area underneath) rather than a polygon.

```r
library(ggridges)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, colour = cut, fill = cut)) +
  geom_density_line(alpha = 0.2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-12-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>